# Ввод символа с клавиатуры java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь заниматься Java по книжке "Java 8 Руководство для начинающих" Герберта Шилдта.
Там есть упражнение на создание игры по угадыванию символов. Я решил ее немного усложнить, добавив наличие 3х попыток и указателя, большее или меньшее относительно загаданного числа было введено игроком.

```
class guess4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        
        char answer = 's';
        System.out.println("Once again playing this game\nYou have three attempts now");
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("it's your " + i + " attempt");
            char a = (char) System.in.read();
            if (a == answer) System.out.println("yes!");
            else if (a < answer) System.out.println("need to +++");
            else System.out.println("need to ---"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Но возникла проблема с тем, что программа принимает переменную только 1 раз.
Примеры вывода для введенных 'a' и 'z':

```
Once again playing this game
You have three attempts now
it's your 1 attempt
a
need to +++
it's your 2 attempt
need to +++
it's your 3 attempt
need to +++
```

```
Once again playing this game
You have three attempts now
it's your 1 attempt
z
need to ---
it's your 2 attempt
need to +++
it's your 3 attempt
need to +++
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вашу проблему _при вводе английских букв_ воспроизвести не удалось; при вводе кириллицы одна буква пропускается, так как метод [`InputStream::read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) считывает _один байт_, а кириллица использует два байта при кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); и в каждом проходе цикла вызывать scanner.next(). Он вернет вам строку, но, полагаю, преобразовать строку для вас не проблема. Немного костыльное решение, но тем не менее:

```
    char answer = 's';
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Once again playing this game\nYou have three attempts now");

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("it's your " + i + " attempt");
        String typed = scanner.next();
        if(typed.length() != 1){
            System.out.println("Only one char is allowed");
            continue;
        }
        char a = typed.charAt(0);
        if (a == answer) System.out.println("yes!");
        else if (a < answer) System.out.println("need to +++");
        else System.out.println("need to ---");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось найти решение

```
class game {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        
        int i = 1;
        char ch, ignore, answer = 's';
        System.out.println("Once again playing this game\nYou have three attempt now");

        one : {
            while (i <=3) {
                System.out.println("This is your " + i + " attempt");
                ch = (char) System.in.read();
                do {
                    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
                } while (ignore != '\n');
    
                if (ch == answer) {
                    System.out.println("yes");
                    break one;
                }
                else if (ch < answer) System.out.println("need to +++");
                else if (ch > answer) System.out.println("need to ---");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Все дело в вот в этой части кода:

```
do {
    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
} while (ignore != '\n');
```

Можете если ее закомментировать //, то ничего работать не будет.

Объяснения из книги:

> Как пояснялось ранее, консольный ввод буферизуется построчно. Это означает,
> что для передачи символов, вводимых с клавиатуры, приходится нажимать клавишу
> , что приводит к формированию последовательности символов перевода строки
> и возврата каретки. Эти символы сохраняются во входном буфере вместе с введенными
> с клавиатуры. Кроме того, если ввести с клавиатуры несколько символов подряд, не нажав клавишу , они так и останутся во входном буфере.
> В рассматриваемом здесь цикле эти символы отбрасываются до тех пор, пока не будет достигнут конец строки. Если не сделать этого, лишние символы будут передаваться
> программе в качестве выбранной буквы, что не соответствует действительности.